# Readings files from a directory

Tags: java

I need to read each file from a directory to parse them individualy when I give a directory structure.

I check if it excists and if its valid .. etc and I can parse the file's individualy.  But I have no idea how to do it :

I had a idea but it doesn't work :

```
String dir = userinput;
File directory = new File(dir);
File files[] = directory.listFiles();

for (File f : files){
    // parsing method    
}
```

I have a method that checks if it's a valid dir or file and I always get a return that the file isn't valid.  If I read them individualy I have no problems

Comment: You should show the check method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the curly brackets before the for and after the close of the for loop are doing, but the logic seems sound enough.  You might want to add some guards like isFile() isDirectory(), but I don't see why adding a parsing method in at the commented position would not work.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @sthupahsmaht fair point I guess, but it's really an answer stating "it will work".  IMO I thought SO was effectively a wiki, so surely answers are a work in progress....

Comment: most certainly. but if not enough information is provided to give a well-informed answer, then a comment is usually more appropriate. sorry for nitpicking, but I get this ALL the time...:)